# Using substring within Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use a substring within the Linq expression, but cannot make it work.  Here is my code:

```
CategoriesById =
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"eventType_1", "Super Classes"},
                {"eventType_2", "Master Classes"},
                {"eventType_3", "Talks"},
                {"eventType_4", "Forums"}
            };

        IEnumerable<CustomerDto> result =
            _jsonSerialiser.Deserialise<ImportDto>(xml).Imports;

        var filteredResult = result
            .Where(s => s.CategoryIds
                .Any(i => CategoriesById.Keys
                    .Contains(i)));
```

The above works but I want to match for the substring of s.CategoryIds. The s.CategoryIds is of type IEnumerable.  Because of this I cannot use .Substring or Split on it.  How can I use .Substring or Split for each s.CategoryIds within the same Linq?

Thanks

Comment: I can not test it right now, so I post it as comment, but I think using `.Where(p => p.SomeProperty == String.Substring(Something))` instead of `Contains` should do a trick

Comment: s is of type IEnumerable but i - isn't; So: var filteredResult = result
            .Where(s => s.CategoryIds
                .Any(i => CategoriesById.Keys
                    .Contains(i.SubString(xxx))))

Comment: you want to match the substring of `s.CategoryIds` with what?

Comment: I would like to match s.CategoryIds to CategoriesById.Keys.  I think Fabjan's solution worked. But I've got one more requirement - I know I am probably pushing here.  What I have now is  var filteredResult = result
            .Where(s => s.CategoryIds
                .Any(i => CategoriesById.Keys
                    .Contains(i.Remove(i.Length - 3))));  This is works, but in some cases the length I would like to remove is 2 instead of 3.  Is it possible to use some sort of comparison within the Contains()?

Answer (score 0):

You can call where on CategoriesById in Any:

```
var filteredResult = result
            .Where(s => s.CategoryIds
                .Any(i => CategoriesById.Keys.Where(c => c.Substring(3).Contains(i)));
```